# Gatsby not finding graphql fragment

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to use GraphQL fragments on a Gatsby site, I tried to follow guides to create this fragment but Gatsby throws an error stating that my fragment does not exist

```
The fragment "PageFragment" does not exist.
```

I located my fragment in a folder called "graphql-fragments" located in the root of the Gatsby project, this folder contains one file called "pageFragment.js" which is my fragment
pageFragment.js

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby";

export const PageFragment = graphql`
  fragment PageFragment on SanityPage {
    slug {
      current
    }
    _rawContent(resolveReferences: { maxDepth: 20 })
    _id
    title
  }
`;
```

I use this fragment on my index page where I also get my error

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby";

export const query = graphql`
  query FrontpageQuery {
    page: sanityPage(_id: { regex: "/(drafts.|)frontpage/" }) {
      ...PageFragment
    }
  }
`;


const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello world
    </div>
  )
}


export default Home
```

Running the graphQL query without the fragment works fine, so this works and I am getting the data I expect

```
export const query = graphql`
  query FrontpageQuery {
    page: sanityPage(_id: { regex: "/(drafts.|)frontpage/" }) {
      slug {
        current
      }
      _rawContent(resolveReferences: { maxDepth: 20 })
      _id
      title
    }
  }
`;
```

It seems like Gatsby is not finding my fragment, any clues to what I'm doing wrong? Running on Gatsby version 2.24.66

Comment: Did you try moving the /graphql-fragments folder into /src folder?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quote from [Gatsby docs:](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#fragments)

> To create a fragment, define it in a query and export it as a named
> export from **any file Gatsby is aware of**. A fragment is available for
> use in any other GraphQL query, regardless of its location in the
> project. Fragments are globally defined in a Gatsby project, so names
> have to be unique.

The file that export the fragment can not be stored in the root folder of the project where gatsby-config.js etc is located. If the Gatsby source files are in a folder called `src` then the file that export the fragment has to be in the `src` folder or one of its subfolders.

As a side note: one thing I sometimes forget is to add `import { graphql } from "gatsby"`, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Thank you for the valid and helpful side note.